# C# server code for send Xtify push

Tags: xtify

I cant seem to find any sample code in C# that shows how to send a simple Xtify push message to a list of registered devices.
I have my Android devices setup and registered to receive messages but how do I send the message from my webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Well C# can use the REST API given here http://developer.xtify.com/display/APIs/Push+API+2.0 directly to send the push message. You can use the HTTpClient if C# create a connection to the server and send the message.